# Symfony + Doctrine + Annotation validation not work in forms

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

I'm using doctrine annotations in my entities definition to define each variable behavior, i.e.:

```
@ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
```

If I submit the form leaving the field empty, it pass the validation, but (of corse) I receive an error about the INSERT statement, because he cannot insert NULL value.
How this could be possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because Symfony does not automatically validate your form input based on Doctrine annotations.

Symfony2 ships with a [Validator](https://github.com/symfony/Validator) component that makes this task easy and transparent though. This component is based on the [JSR303 Bean Validation specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303).

Read up on the implementation at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

Here is an example of Validator annotation that might assist you:

```
// Acme/TaskBundle/Entity/Example.php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Example
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\MaxLength(50)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    public $parameter;
}
```

Comment: my `$form->isValid()` returns always true! why?

Comment: I assume because you have not defined any rules/constraints, so given that no rules are defined, no rules are broken, the form is thus valid.

Comment: Read the manual on [Symfony Form Validation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/forms.html)

Comment: I've read it and in chapter _Validation and Forms_ it says that form forms I can use isValid...and the Validator is not needed...So I don't understand where I should specify this contraints...

Comment: See my answer, I updated it with an example of using annotations for you.

Comment: You can also define all the constraints in one file, in the validation.yml. [link](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/validation.html#constraint-configuration)